# Monkey patch created_by and modified_by django

Tags: python, django, monkeypatching

I have an application deployed an year ago.  In production I am unwilling to change all models manually to add the `created_by` and `modified_by` fields as it would be little risky.

Is there anyway, we can achieve it with less amount of coding we could fix it (at least for the future transactions it should add those fields to every model?)

I was thinking of monkey patching it, but dont know how to implement it?

```
from django.apps import apps
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

model_list = apps.get_models()
#-- Monkey Patch


for model in model_list:
  if model != get_user_model():
    model.add_to_class('created_by', models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True, null=True))
    model.add_to_class('modified_by', models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True, null=True))

        
  def save(self):
      if self.pk:
          self.created_by = request.user.id #not sure, how I would get the user here from request 
          self.modified_by = request.user.id
      return super(model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

  model.add_to_class("save", save)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider having base abstract model that contains those fields and inherit your other models from it.  Not sure how it will work with migrations though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way will be to create an abstract class with this two fields and inherit from it in every class. only thing to keep in mind is you will need to provide an initial value for them:

```py
class UserAction(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

# Inherit from UserAction class
class MyClasses(UserAction):
    # ... fields
```